# Oracle Trigger Permissions

Tags: oracle, permissions, triggers, privileges, ora-01031

I want to create a trigger owned by user A for a table that is owned by user B.  What permissions must I set on B.table to avoid an ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GRANT CREATE ANY TRIGGER ON b TO a
```

There is no way to grant a permission to create a trigger on a certain table.